# How do i create a derived class with certain constructors? (python)

Tags: python, class

This is my class:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, playernum):
    self.playernum = playernum

    def play_turn(self, board):
        """This method is passed an instance of ConnectFour.  
           It should examine the board (using methods on the ConnectFour class...
           assume you have it) and eventually call board.play_turn and return"""
    pass
```

So far I understand that if I do:

```
class Human(Player):
```

It will make Human() a derived class of Player.

What I would like to do is have a constructor playernum inside this class. Then take the overridden play_turn and print a player number(ie. playernum)...I just want to know how this would be implemented... do I repeat

```
def play_turn(self,board):
```

inside the Human class or do I simply put

```
class Human(Player):
    play_turn
```

and inside the

```
play_turn(self,board):
    "put"
    print playernum
```

I'm kind of new to derivations of classes and the logic behind it. Any input will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a constructor playernum"? A constructor is the `__init__` function (from inside the class) or the calling to the class itself (from outside the class). So this phrase doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @abarnert I meant that playernum from the Player class is used within the parameters of the Human class so I can use the playernum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that to override a method from a parent class, you 'repeat' the method inside the derived class.  Your code should end up looking something like:

```
class Human(Player):
    def play_turn(self, board):
        print self.playernum
```

If `play_turn` is meant to contain shared logic for its derived classes, you want to call the parents' method first:

```
class Human(Player):
    def play_turn(self, board):
        super(Human, self).play_turn(board)
        print self.playernum
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add a prompt within this class do i just put 'var = raw_input("which column would you like to drop the chip? ")' and then print that with 'print var'? It seems I'm overthinking this...